# Connect my domain name with Apache

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain

I want to connect my subdomain that I created before, with Apache server. When I type the subdomain name in my web browser to get response and to be able to see my website. I created **A Record** for my subdomain and I connected it with my Elastic IP from my web server at the Amazon AWS.

How can I connect the Apache server to response when I type subdomain in my browser?
I am asking because I am new to all these services.
Thank you.

Comment: Is the security group open on port 80 for that ec2 instance? Does it work using the IP address and not the domain? Does the nslookup for your subdomain return the elastic IP?

Comment: Yes the security group is open on port 80 for that ec2 instance.No it doesn't work with the IP address.And if i do the nslookup it returns me the elastic IP.

Comment: I think this is your solution:https://serverfault.com/questions/300015/how-to-create-a-subdomain-in-ec2-amazon-com